# make drawerlayout half way open

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

so I was working with this drawerlayout and I want to open it half way.

My main objective is to open the drawer not from the side but from the inside of the screen and follow the x just like swiping from the side.

I don't want to use any 3rd party library.